# Re-write the for loop function in python, need help to understand better

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I need  help to re-write that for loop function with indentations below

```
y = [g(x,y) for x in xs for y in xs if f(x,y)]
```

full code is here

```
g = lambda x,y:(x-y) 
f = lambda x,y: x>y 
xs = [1,2,3,4] 
y = [g(x,y) for x in xs for y in xs if f(x,y)]
```

Comment: Why do you need expand that list comprehension?

Comment: That code is an example, I need a simpler form of for loop to understand so I can visualize.

Comment: Do you understand the lambda's?

Comment: Not really, I'm trying to understand it. Any suggestions?

Comment: The first can be defined as a function that takes two arguments and returns the difference between the first and second argument.

Comment: Yes, I got that part. Why do we need lambda? Can't we just use def A(x,y): return x-y

Comment: You'll have to Google for why we need the lambda form.  Many people prefer the *standard* function definition syntax.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for your time and help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = []
for a in xs:
    for b in xs:
        if f(a, b):
            y.append(g(a, b))
```

Comment: Thank you, It is easier for me to understand the function.